# Getting error during Jenkins build "fatal error: opensslconf-i386.h"

Tags: linux, openssl, rhel

Jenkins pipeline fails with the below error while running in Rhel 7.9 worker node

`/usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:13:30: fatal error: opensslconf-i386.h: No such file or directory #include "opensslconf-i386.h"`

I tried to install `libssl-dev:i386` on Rhel 7.9 but I am getting an error "No package libssl-dev:i386 available"

This is the commands that was executed in the pipeline
`sudo make package ARCH=linux_32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installed `openssl-devel.i686` and the error got resolved

`yum install openssl-devel.i686`